Transformer calculations for a voltage-fed push-pull converter
I am designing my first voltage-fed push-pull converter, and I got stuck during the transformer sizing process. I am not exactly sure how to proceed. I have determined the primary and secondary peak currents, as well as the number of turns, but I don't know what to do next...
How can I accurately determine the required core cross-sectional area, wire diameters, etc.? Thank you for your help.
My calculations so far:


Calculations seem reasonable.  Note that your Lx is quite large, and C small; this isn't inconsistent, we can do some spot checks to compare:

\$Z_o = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$ should be much less than the output rating.  Suppose a step load is applied to the output, and D and Vin are held constant: the rectifier looks like a constant-voltage source, thus the left side of L is at a virtual ground, a supernode with respect to orthogonal signals (the ensuing transient).  The output node therefore has a parallel resonant LC tank equivalent circuit, with this Zo.  For a step load change, the corresponding peak voltage change is Zo Istep or 25.6V, or a 6.4% ripple fraction.  This is likely acceptable.
\$F_o = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{L C}}\$ should be much less than Fsw.  It's 2.3kHz, so this checks out as well.

The main thing is, if you can tolerate DCM at Iout(min) (or some higher breakpoint for that matter), L can be much smaller, and C increased modestly to compensate.  Larger C is also desirable for using cheaper electrolytics, where the larger value is necessary to get a suitable ripple rating.
The low Zo has a downside that the startup transient is that much worse, but this (along with control compensation, and startup/fault behavior generally) is far and away best solved by using current-mode control.  And with a single output and filter choke, this is easily implemented.
Consider:
https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/InverterProto2.png (links to my website) 
(not embedding a copy as it's not particularly presentable, maintaining copyright, and, this is a sidetrack to the question anyways) 
If you're using a voltage-mode controller like TL494, SG3524, etc., consider a scheme like this.  Rectifier output current (inductor state) can be sensed with a shunt resistor, and controlled to a setpoint determined by an outer error amp, so that peak output current is controlled immediately and at all times, completely obviating startup and fault current issues, and the outer voltage control can operate faster (critically, above the LC double-pole: controlling L and C separately splits their poles apart!), improving performance further (smaller L and C can be used -- at least, in control terms, if not limited by other considerations like above!).
More reading here: TL494 step-down converter with CC/CV
Anyway, on to transformer design.

There is no analytical expression for a transformer core: too many shapes are available, in discrete sizes, so nothing more than an estimate can be made.  Instead, an iterative method applies.
Consider a given core:

You need to fit enough turns on it, to keep Bpk within limits.
Bpk limits depend on efficiency requirement and component temp rise, and the core material's loss parameters.
You need to fit thick enough wire (or enough strands as litz) in the winding window, to meet eff/temp limits, given copper resistivity, and any eddy current / skin / proximity effect considerations.

The first affects cross-sectional area, the second affects winding window.  Copper goes up with turns, while core area goes down, so we have simultaneous equations.  Combined, we get an invariant, a sort of size factor, though in terms of an area product (m4) rather than linear dimension, or (core or overall) volume.
As a starting point, probably something EE38 to ETD42 would be of interest here.  Frequency is typical, figure Bpk ~ 0.1T for typical power ferrite (e.g. N97, 3C90, etc.), and you get turns from there, then check what size of wire you can fit on the thing.  Go back and forth, trying nearby core sizes, until you've found the optimal choice.
Basic design equations are simple proportions:
$$ A_L = \mu_r \mu_0 \frac{A_e}{l_e} \\ 
L = A_L N^2 $$
Note that \$\mu_r\$ of the core material, is effectively reduced by air gap:
$$ \mu_\text{eff} = \frac{l_e}{\frac{l_e}{\mu_r} + l_g} $$
Note that energy is stored in the air gap: magnetic energy density (the Maxwell stress*) is \$e = \frac{B^2}{2 \mu_0}\$.  Times the volume of the air gap, this gives (most of) the energy stored in a gapped core -- this is the case for ferrite cored inductors (coupled or otherwise).  (A flyback transformer might be better described as a coupled inductor, as it stores and releases energy alternately.  An ideal transformer merely transforms power instantaneously: energy storage is a nonideality.)  The energy actually stored in the core is small, as you can see from µ being in the denominator, and µr being fairly large in most ferrites.
*Because pressure is dimensionally identical to energy density!
(This won't be so important for the power transformer, as a forward converter transformer approximates an ideal one.  A small air gap may still be desirable, to increase magnetizing current and thus flux balancing during dead time.  This is of course applicable to the filter choke, if you'll be designing it too.)
We can write the flux in the core like so:
$$ N = \frac{V}{4 B_\text{pk} A_e F} $$
Note that the \$\frac{V}{4 F}\$ part describes the flux of the waveform (terminal or circuit flux): V peak for square wave (times 2D where D is the maximum per-channel duty, or as-is to include up to full 50%), 1/4 because flux alternates above and below zero in this (full wave) topology, and 1/F because flux is volt-seconds, the area under the curve.  B is flux density (per m2) and is field value so doesn't include turns, and we need a factor of turns to go between.  (If you like, you can assign a "per turn" pseudo-unit to Ae or B, to make it easier to track in-circuit (times turns) and field (it just is what it is) quantities.)
For the windings, resistance is simply the wire size and length:
$$ R = \rho \frac{N l_\text{MT}}{A} $$
where lMT is the mean length per turn: basically, take the circumference around the bobbin, for an average radius.  Turns lower on the bobbin will be shorter, but this is balanced by turns higher on the bobbin.  Assuming you fill the whole bobbin; and if you don't, you save some length, and it ends up an overestimate; safe enough.
All that wire takes up area:
$$ A_W W_F \ge 2 N A $$
Where AW is the winding window area (a bobbin parameter -- you're not winding directly on the core, so lose some area because of bobbin thickness and tolerances), WF the winding factor (typ. 0.2-0.7 depending on wire type/style, amount and kind of tape used, isolation requirements, etc.), N the turns and A the cross-section per wire.  2, because it's a transformer as you need as much copper for the primary as secondary.  Or, really this should be the sum:
$$ A_W W_F \ge N_P A_P + N_S A_S $$
for respective primary and secondary turns and areas.
And for round wire of course, we have \$A = \pi r^2\$ or whatever.
Probably, the primary here will be either foil (preferably just 1+1 turn (layered), though 2, maybe even 3 turns side-by-side, may be acceptable depending on form factor), or litz.  You need to handle a lot of current, so it will need to be beefy; litz would be many wires/cables in parallel, laid out across the bobbin to give a wide facing area.
Litz has a lower winding factor (typically <0.4), so keep that in mind.  Litz also gives more leakage inductance: for precisely the same reason that the strands share current -- magnetic field penetrates through the cable/winding -- so too, the leakage inductance is increased, relative to an equivalent solid or foil/sheet winding.  Thus, you may need more interleaving when using litz.  This is especially relevant for the push-pull primary, where leakage between ends of the primary is as (or more?) important as leakage to the secondary.
With resistance, turns, area, etc., add it up, apply current to get power, and come up with a total estimate for power dissipation.  Something in the EE38 to ETD42 range should dissipate 10 or 20W pretty easily, give or take airflow.
Probably, this leaves plenty of room for insulation, and interleaving.  You probably want to do the primary as sheet (as mentioned), or bifilar pairs connected alternately (i.e. each pair of turns is a 1:1 section of the primary, and these are all connected in parallel at the transformer terminals).
Other further reading: 
Magnetic Component Design | Tim Williams - this is rather old, and probably a bit rough or could stand to be reviewed or whatever, but has most of what's needed there.
Design of Switch Mode Power Supplies | Dr. Heinz Schmidt-Walter - handy online SMPS design / waveform plotting tool

Funny I have linked to your previous answer to a similar question, and here you are.

Honestly I don't even remember anymore, which posts/articles I've written, and that are any good. I appreciate the reference :)

Hi mate, thanks for the valuable answer!  I think I will have more questions in the future.. :)

I should be able to help you as I have done a similar converter.
From the top of my head, I can tell you that the transformer core EI40 or EE40 would be on the edge at 500W or actually underpowered.
EE42 to EE48 cores should be sufficient for your purpose here.
Here is a link to a chart of ferrite cores and their power handling capacity:
https://www.mag-inc.com/getattachment/Products/Ferrite-Cores/PowerDesign-FerriteCatalog2017.pdf
The converter I had made was running at 400W on an EI40 ferrite core from a PC power supply. The transformer was running relatively hot and I had a fan blowing at it the whole time.
I was also using push-pull topology, and tested it up to over 100kHz but settled at 50kHz.
You should be aware that the 60A primary current will definitely heat up the wire and that the necessary size wire likely won't fit inside EI40, so you should go up to the next size.
An ER core has a round center instead of a square one, which helps reduce leakage inductance and losses.
Because there are so many different cores to choose from, and it's a headache navigating through all of the options, I can't recommend a specific one.
I mentioned EI40 or EE40 because it was one of the most common cores found in PC power supplies, but you might have something else on hand.
You can actually use two EE40 transformers in parallel, as I have seen done in inverters rated for 600W.
It is a fairly simple solution which allows using a singe control IC (most often TL494) for both, it cuts the primary currents in half and splits the heat between the two transformers.
You will still need a fan blowing through to keep things cool enough, you can choose any of those 12V brushless fans of almost any power, you can use a quiet one, as long as there is air streaming through you should be fine.
Don't forget to use a fine litz wire (should be less than 0.2mm diameter for each strand for 100kHz) to reduce the skin effect losses.
If you like calculations, here is an answer to a similar question by someone more knowledgeable about this:
How can I calculate the size of a power ferrite core transformer?
Regarding the rectifier diodes in your circuit, I would suggest using a rectifier bridge instead, because that will cut their peak reverse voltage requirement in half AND you will need half as many turns of wire for the secondary.
Regarding the inductor Lx, though I understand it is crucial for regulation and as an "impedance converter", if you need it to be of that large value due to ripple voltage requirements, you could easily reduce its value by half and use a 10uF to 22uF (or larger) capacitor.
Finally, there is a trick to use even fewer turns of wire on the secondary, as well additionally cut the peak reverse voltage requirements for the diodes: you could run it as a double half-wave rectifier, a.k.a. Delon circuit.
Below is an example schematic (can't be simulated in our program, unfortunately):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Finally, there is the issue of voltage spikes across your MOSFETs.
According to simple theory, your MOSFETs are exposed to twice the supply voltage.
In practice and in a "deeper" theory, you have so-called "leakage inductance" of your transformer windings, which produces voltage spikes a few times larger than the supply voltage, in this case up to 100V, possibly more.
Normally, those spikes are greatly reduced by an RC snubber across each MOSFET's drain and source, with the practical values I have seen going from 4.7 nF to 10 nF and from 2.2 Ω to 10 Ω (at least 1/2 W to 1 W rated power).
The cheap Chinese 300 W and 600 W inverters I looked at used a single RC snubber (10 nF and 10 Ω) going between the drain electrodes of the two MOSFETs.
Some designs use TVS diodes, but you should be careful about their rated voltage and the voltage at which they actually clamp the spikes - the second one can be more than 50% higher and leave your component unprotected from the higher voltage spike.
Personally, I went with 8 mΩ, 60 V rated MOSFETs (higher is better), because I didn't have anything better available, and I used a Zener-capacitor-diode combination between drain and source of each transistor.
Here is how I did it:

simulate this circuit
The beauty of this approach is that you precisely control the point at which the peak voltages get shunted through the diodes to the capacitors and none of the diodes need to be the fast type because all diodes (to my knowledge) have forward response time of no more than 1 ns (nano-second) and the Zener is paralleled with capacitors which take care of the fast transients.
Zener diode's job here is to maintain its Zener voltage and shunt excess current.
Because fast transients are shunted by the capacitors C1 and C2 near the MOSFETs, the Zener diode can be further away from both and you can use a single Zener for both MOSFETs.
Using a resistor instead of a Zener would give an unpredictable and unstable shunting voltage which would depend on the amount of energy in the peaks.
The Zener voltage is chosen to be as high as possible so that the least amount of spike energy is taken away from the transformer (increases efficiency), but to be significantly lower (at least 10-15% lower) than the maximum Vds voltage rating of the MOSFETs so that there is a margin of safety.
You do need to make sure the Zener can dissipate all of the power, so at least a 2-3 W rated diode would be necessary, 5 W would be recommended, and you can also use two 24 V 5W Zener diodes in series.

Using two transformers in parallel has the added bonus that -- if a synchronizable controller is used -- they can be run in quadrature, canceling out input and output current ripple, so that smaller capacitors can be used.  The reduced current in each inverter also eases design, relative to trying to parallel MOSFETs.

@TimWilliams Exactly, it just cuts all the burdens in half, although it is hard to find a multiphase push-pull PWM controller; TL494 solutions I came across simply ran two same outputs to two pairs of MOSFETs on two separate transformers, no phase splitting. I had started making a 3- or 4-phase forward inverter based on a controller IC from a PC motherboard, but didn't finish it, opting instead for a single large toroid ferrite core.  I have come up with a two-way half/bridge push-pull design for my 160V solar panels to 12V batteries, then back to 160V LED stadium lights.

@TimWilliams However, based on my bad experience with sharing my design ideas here (my last one regarding simplest 555 discrete design got closed very quickly, without suggestions that would make it stay open), I am not so happy about sharing here anymore.

Yeah, syncing TL494 probably needs a phase-shift network and various support components, or a reference clock and divider (e.g. LTC6902).

@EdinFifić - Hi, Re: "based on my bad experience {...} I am not so happy about sharing here anymore" - I am very sorry to hear that & I can imagine how demoralising that is :( As another site member advised in comments on that Q, if you want to publicly discuss why the voting (both up/down votes & votes-to-close) went the way that it did, then our [meta] is the place to do that (it would be for 10k members only, as the Q was auto-deleted). I didn't participate in that voting, but if you want my personal views, I can open a chatroom with you (or you can ask others in main chat) your choice :)

@SamGibson Thank you very much. I would welcome that. I don't know if you can see my closed "question", regarding my simplest discrete 555 circuit. I have seen plenty of questions closed where no details were given, and no effort shown. Inappropriate questions were closed, but some explanatory comments were given where effort was shown, and the poster was given a chance to follow the suggestions to keep it open.  I was given a couple somewhat constructive advices from one person voting to close it, regarding the circuit or expectations from engineers, that was it. It felt personal.

@EdinFifić - Hi, This is just a short reply as I have to go to a meeting and we shouldn't discuss things here: Re: "I don't know if you can see my closed "question"" Yes, I can. "It felt personal." I understand that :( However I don't believe it was intended that way. || I will setup a chatroom when I'm back online this evening EU time, and invite you to it.

@SamGibson Thank you again.

Hi mate, thanks for the valuable answer! As I dive deeper into studying things, more and more questions come up! :D

@slimcolt You are welcome. I forgot to mention the issues with inductive kickback on MOSFETs, the 4-diode rectifier bridge instead of two diodes, and another possible solution to cut your secondary voltage in half. I hope I don't forget to add it in later.

Thank you again for your help! The bridge rectifier is certainly worth considering in this case. I chose a large inductance because I want the converter to operate in CCM mode over the widest possible range. I have just performed a steady-state analysis to understand how the push-pull converter operates in DCM mode. If my calculations are correct, the output voltage is:
Vout = Vin * (Ns/Np) * D/(D + D2), where D2 is the time during which the inductance releases its stored energy.

I also examined how Vout changes with D2. The worst-case scenario is when D2 = D, because in that case, Vout = (Vin/2) * (Ns/Np). When D2 → 0, then Vout = Vin * (Ns/Np). I still need to analyze how Vout behaves when I reduce the output current down to the lower limit of CCM, and beyond. This is not an easy task for me :/ :D
In addition, I also plan to calculate the RMS currents, but I will post a new question about that! :D

To clarify: The worst-case scenario is when D2 = 1 - D, which happens exactly at the DCM boundary.
Vout = Vin * (Ns/Np) * D, and because of this, the output voltage drops significantly!

@slimcolt You have certainly done more calculations and analysis of that part than I did. I go into mathematics only as deep as I have to go, as long as I got the basics down and the circuit performing well. I also do practical testing and measurement in parallel, so I learn  both theoretically and practically. I am still adding a couple things to my answer, sorry it is a lot of text but I'm sharing what I remember when I remember it and get the time to write it.

Hvala Edo.  Some questions as i (not OP) have been working on similar.
thanks for the Delon multiplier, i hadn't thought about it. it doesn't change core requirements, though, right? half the voltage, twice the current, you maybe need half the windings but at twice the thickness? Similarly the diodes would need to carry twice the current, as well, so as a first order approximation it is all the same, or am i missing something?   finally, can you comment on flux walk and how it may be avoided? Thanks again for the great answer, dovidjenja, and i hope you don't mind the diminutive greeting :)

@rohmeooo I was taken by surprise with your greeting. Are you a Bosnian, do you know me? Regarding your questions, you are correct on using half as many turns, twice the wire thickness (thin litz wire for high frequencies), twice the diode current.  As for flux walking, apparently it is not a problem when using MOSFETs, especially in a low voltage high-current circuit, because they have positive tempco and automatically reduce their own current which brings them back into balance. Just make sure both primary halves have equal inductance and resistance as much as possible.

Yes born there pre-war, USA now, no I (probably) don't know you.   I found the same thing regarding tempco of mosfets, but it's still scary as i don't know how exactly to quantify it besides observing that it works well across various temperatures/loads/etc.  Not sure if i get a particularly mismatched set of mosfets and a particularly leaky transformer what may happen.  For instance is it better to use dual mosfets so their Rds stays reasonably matched, but then they will stay at roughly the same temps, too?
Thanks for the discussion and the usual great answers!

@rohmeooo Which place from and how old are you, if you don't mind me asking?  As far as I know, you shouldn't worry much about a slight mismatch which is usually the case. If you have an LCR meter, it will greatly help you. Also, the RdsON can be measured by turning the MOSFET on (on a test platform) with +10 V on its gate and 1.00 A constant current through drain-source channel, then measuring the voltage drop closest to the leads of the MOSFET at mV setting on your voltmeter, getting fairly accurate value in mΩ. And don't worry, if the cheap Chinese inverters work, so should yours.  :D
